# Issues with Android ImageView

Tags: java, android

I have an application which allows the user to upload pictures from gallery or take photos using camera. everything works fine, but when i display the bitmap in the image view, the image view will be bigger then the required size, trying to fill the parent even if i had set it's layout params to wrap content.

why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `BitmapFactory` to resize the bitmap after calling `view.layout()` and `view.measure()` on the `ImageView` you're using.  Use the `view.getWidth()` and `view.getHeight()` as the desired width and height, respectively, for the `BitmapFactory` resize procedure.

Comment: thanks for your reply. what i have now is that i use the bitmapfactory.decodeFile(path) to retrieve the image. do you mind if you go a little in depth on how can i achieve what you are explaning?

Comment: Try  creating a scaled bitmap using what I suggested: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: @footprint, don't forget to accept the answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is your ImageView inside a ScrollView container? If it is, set fillViewPort to FALSE.  Check also width and height of Layout container, should be WRAP_CONTENT also.